# How can i deactivate zoom by default on web application?

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, browser, zooming

I am working on a web application and my client is using Google Chrome on Windows (I am also using Chrome but on Linux) and when they enter the application, there is default zoom which correspond to my 125% zoom but when they try to change the zoom it is already 100%. I would like to know if someone already had this problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: It's probably the "scale and layout" setting in the Windows display properties. You have no control over this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into settings > advanced > privacy and security > site settings and somewhere there should be the zoom levels option. Check it out and let me know.